# Pixel 6 Pro Very Strange Artifacts

Tags: artifacts

This is my friends old photo, and many are convinced that this is a ghost, hehe, but you can clearly see curved bars that make up the image. I've spent way too long trying to find the answer, can any of you solve the mystery?[image: graveyard photo]

Answer (score 6):

Looks to be just drawn on in Photoshop or something, using the brush tool and clone stamp or similar.

Comment: No, he's an old guy, doesn't use Photoshop type editors, and didn't tamper with the image in any way.

Comment: @Judith the image is obviously "tampered" with - there is a signature/logo at bottom right- that didn't come straight out of the camera. This photograph has gone through obvious post-processing. Someone is not being truthful here.

Comment: Additionally, aside from the so-called "ghost" (lol), the image was given some HDR or similar treatment. The sky blooming around all of the trees branches in the focus and background are a dead giveaway of some sort of processing.

Answer (score -2):

I used to be a photographer and I think what happened here is the person was moving while the camera rims was open for a long exposure.